# Assembly program to print 'a' to 'z' using stack, loop cx and dx

Tags: loops, assembly, stack

I've got an assignment to make an assembly program which print 'a' to 'z' vertically line by line using stack, loop cx and dx.
Can anyone help me please.

This is program of printing a to z, but i dont have an idea how to use stack cx and dx in my program:

```
.data
l1c db 0ah,0dh,"S" 
.code 
main proc
mov ax @data 
mov ds,ax 
mov al,48 
mov cx,10 
d: 
mov dl,al 
mov ah,2 
int 21h 
call linechange 
inc al 
loop d
mov ah,4ch 
int 21h 
main endp 

;Procedure
linechange proc 
lea dx,l1c 
mov ah,9 
int 21h 
ret 
linechnage endp 
end main
```

(this is the program which i made by my self)

Comment: The best way to get help here is to first try something. If you get stuck, do some research, make an attempt at fixing things yourself, and only then ask a specific question about your attempts, showing what you have tried. Questions asking for complete solutions without demonstrating research effort usually get downvoted and closed.

Comment: i have to use 3 things stack , cx and dx

Comment: I voted for reopen because it's quite clear to me what is asked.

Comment: This is how I would do this: mov al,'a'
loop:
mov ah,0x0E
int 0x10
mov cl,al
mov al,10
int 0x10
mov al,13
int 0x10
mov al,cl
inc al
cmp al,'z'+1
jne loop
jmp $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your teacher wanted to avoid a "clever" solution like:

```
.MODEL SMALL

.STACK 1000h

.DATA
    smart_out   db 'a',13,10,'b',13,10,'b',13,10,'c',13,10,'d',13,10,'e',13,10
                db 'f',13,10,'g',13,10,'h',13,10,'i',13,10,'j',13,10,'k',13,10
                db 'l',13,10,'m',13,10,'n',13,10,'o',13,10,'p',13,10,'q',13,10
                db 'r',13,10,'s',13,10,'t',13,10,'u',13,10,'v',13,10,'w',13,10
                db 'x',13,10,'y',13,10,'z',13,10,'$'

.CODE
main:
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax

    mov ah, 9
    mov dx, OFFSET smart_out
    int 21h

    mov ax, 4C00h
    int 21h
END main
```

You are supposed to output this with a `LOOP` (`CX` needed). In a loop you need to preserve at least `AX` and `CX` since you never know if a procedure like `INT 21h` will change it. A call to `INT 21h / 9` fulfills the third condition since it needs a value in `DX`:

```
.MODEL SMALL

.STACK 1000h                ; Reserve space for stack and initialize stack pointer

.DATA
l1c db 0dh, 0ah, '$'        ; Dollar-sign!

.CODE
main PROC
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax

    mov al, 'a'
    mov cx, 26

    d:
    push ax                 ; Store AX (AL is a part of AX)
    push cx                 ; Store CX

    mov dl, al
    mov ah, 2
    int 21h

    mov ah, 9
    mov dx, OFFSET l1c
    int 21h

    pop cx                  ; Restore CX & AX in reversed push-order
    pop ax

    inc al
    loop d                  ; Loops until cx == 0

    mov ah, 4ch
    int 21h
main ENDP

END main
```